# Average in excel with different ranges

Tags: vba, excel, average

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I could not find a good answer for it here or elsewhere.

I would like to average sums with different lengths. The example dataset is in the image, with sales numbers for different shops per week. How would I compute the average for say, week 5-7 without doing it manually? The periods with sales in the different shops will change both in length and position in the matrix. Is this possible with VBA/Macro?

[IMAGE HERE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avGj8.png)

For shop#1 I would like the macro to give me two different averages; one for sales in week 2-3, and one for week 5-7.

The dataset I'm currently working on is a 400x50, all with varying lengths. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean 2-3 and 5-7 for shop 1?

Comment: Yes, sorry. week 2-3 and 5-7 for shop#1

Comment: similarly 1-2,4 and 6-7 for shop 2?

Comment: Yes, please. If you could help with a formula with dynamic range or some sort, I think I'll be able to figure out the autofill.

Comment: Please do try to make up your own code before asking for help. If you do not know the basics, please consider reading up the plentiful relevant articles online or consulting a <strike> self-proclaimed </strike> expert of the field.

Comment: How do you want the output presented?  Although your question shows the original data, it shows no attempt at a solution, and does not show how you want the results presented.  Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ok, I missed the point where averages should be done by groups and not for the whole period. So the answer below is not really relevant.

You could `SUMIF` all non blank cells and then divide by the `COUNTIF` of all non blank cells:

```
=SUMIF(B2:H2;"<>"&"")/COUNTIF(B2:H2;"<>"&"")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this returns only one average for the two different kind of sales. 

What I would like to know is the average for week 2-3 and the average for 5-7 respectively. By hand this is of course 5,5 and 4, but I would like to autofill this without having to select the weeks by hand. 

This is because there might have been a sale on at weeks 5-7, which makes it different than week 2-3.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function MULTIAVERAGE(rng As Range) As String
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim rngelement As Range, avgarray(), i As Long

Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Worksheet.UsedRange)
For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        If Not IsEmpty(rng(r, c)) Then
                If rngelement Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngelement = rng(r, c)
                Else
                    Set rngelement = Union(rng(r, c), rngelement)
                End If
            Else
                If Not rngelement Is Nothing Then
                    ReDim Preserve avgarray(i)
                    avgarray(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rngelement)
                    Set rngelement = Nothing
                    i = i + 1
                End If
        End If
    Next c
Next r

If Not rngelement Is Nothing Then
    ReDim Preserve avgarray(i)
    avgarray(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rngelement)
'    Set rngelement = Nothing
'    i = i + 1
End If

'Dim avgarraystr() As String
'    ReDim avgarray(i)
'For j = 0 To i
'    avgarraystr(j) = CStr(avgarray(j))
'Next j
MULTIAVERAGE = Join(avgarray, " | ")
End Function
```

Gives results `5.5 | 4` and `3 | 5 | 4.5` respectively. **I will not comment it**; even though the general idea is good, OP's lack of specification and code warrants no grounds for providing help. He can make amends by putting in the effort for understanding it.

If anyone (including but not restricted to OP) feels like commenting it, go ahead, I'm welcoming such changes.